# What is $h^0(\mathcal O_F)$ where $F$ is a fiber of a normal surface over a smooth curve?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Lately I am studying the bend-and-break, and I follow the proof in the following note written by Olivier Debarre:

http://www.math.ens.fr/~debarre/M2.pdf

There is a detail that I just cannot go through in the top of page 92, the situation here is: there is a normal surface $S$ and a smooth curve $C$ with a flat morphism $\pi: S \to C$, and we have a fiber $F$ of $\pi$ in $S$ over $C$ which is not integral and has no embedded point. I already know that the genus of the fiber $F$ which is a curve in $S$ is $0$. But I just can't understand why this implies that $h^0(F, \mathcal O_F) = 1$.

Hope somebody can help me get through this, thanks!

Comment: Holomorphic functions over connected, compact complex varieties are constant (Liouville theorem, essentially).

Comment: But it is not necessarily over $\mathbb C$, it is over an algebraically closed field $k$. And I don't know if it is connected yet. Connectedness of this $F$ seems to be a result of $h^0=1$....

Comment: of characteristic 0, I guess. So you can use Lefschetz principle or something like that. Anyway, your fiber must be connected (I guess you forgot to say this), otherwise the result is obviously not true.

Comment: I am so confused because I cannot understand what the condition of having no embedded point here is about.

Comment: It seems that $F$ needs to be connected, but all I know is there is a dense open subset $U$ of $C$ such that every fiber of $\pi$ over points in $U$ is $\mathbb P^1$, maybe this gives connectedness of $F$?

Comment: Crossposted from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1146618/what-is-h0-mathcal-o-f-where-f-is-a-fiber-of-a-normal-surface-over-a-smoo --- you should not do that!

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi: the difficulty is that $F$ might be non-reduced. Anyway, Qing Liu answered this question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333745/degenerations-of-mathbbp1/334165#334165

Comment: @ArtiePrendergast-Smith I am sorry, it is  my first time asking a question here, I actually don't get the system here entirely yet...

Comment: In the situation here, the ground field could be of positive characteristic...

Comment: @BenLim Thank you so much! But it seems that $X$ needs to be integral (or at least reduced) in your argument.

Comment: @user50190 I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you misinterpreted the top of page 92 of Debarre's notes.

At that stage Debarre works with a flat morphism $\pi: S\to \overline{T}$, where $S$ is a normal surface and the general fiber of $\pi$ is a smooth rational curve.

He then assumes that every fiber of $\pi$ is integral. Then flatness etc. implies that every fiber of $\pi$ is a smooth rational curve (middle of page 91) and hence $S$ is a ruled surface over $T$. This implies that the two sections $T_0$ and $T_\infty$ have both negative self-intersection and one easily deduces a contradiction from this  (first paragraph of page 92).

This implies that $\pi$ has at least one fiber $F$ which is not integral, hence this fiber $F$ is either a multiple fiber of has several irreducible components, or a combination of this.

However, $\pi$ is proper and flat, and the generic fiber is connected. This implies that every fiber of $\pi$ is connected. 
(See e.g., [Number of irreducible and connected components constant in flat families](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114898/number-of-irreducible-and-connected-components-constant-in-flat-families) )

In particular, $F$ is a connected, but it may be nonreduced, and hence $h^0(\mathcal{O}_F)$ can be larger than one.

Using that $\pi$ is flat you get that every fiber is a connected curve with arithmetic genus $0$. In particular, every irreducible component of $F_{red}$ is a rational curve.

Debarre then consider $S''$, a resolution of singularities of $S$. In this way he introduces further rational curves, and obtains that every fiber of $S''\to T$ consists of rational curves only.