# Bertini theorem for connectedness

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-varieties

Let $X$ be a geometrically irreducible, possibly singular projective variety over an infinite field $k$. Assume that the dimension of $X$ is at least 2. Can there exist a hyperplane section of $X$ that is not geometrically connected?

Comment: What is "geometrically connected"?

Comment: Just take a smooth quadric $Q\subset \mathbb{P}^3$, a point $p\in Q$, $X=Q\smallsetminus\{p\}$, and the tangent hyperplane to $Q$ at $p$.

Comment: @abx But $Q \setminus \{p\}$ is not a projective variety?

Comment: @KevinCasto the question was edited in response to abx's comment.

Comment: Anyways, you may be able to craft an answer from part A of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114898/number-of-irreducible-and-connected-components-constant-in-flat-families

Comment: @KevinCasto I don't think we can guarantee normality of hyperplane sections.

Comment: @vrz Look at the theorem of Deligne in the second answer -- even without normality, you get that the number of connected components is lower semicontinuous. So if the sections are connected generically, they must all be connected.

Comment: Checkout Fulton Hansen connectedness theorem for far more generalization.

Answer (score 2):

Kevin Casto's comment appears to do the trick. But in case a reference would be helpful, here is a result from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.1978) by Martinelli, Naranjo, and Pirola:

> **Theorem 1.1:** Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, $X$ an irreducible projective variety over $k$, and $f:X\to\mathbb{P}_k^n$ a morphism. If $r\geq n+1-\text{dim}\,f(X)$, then for any $r$-dimensional linear subvariety $L\subseteq \mathbb{P}_k^n$, $f^{-1}(L)$ is connected.

In particular, if $\text{dim}\,f(X)\geq 2$, every hyperplane section is geometrically connected.